# The best way to resolve display username by SID?

Tags: c#, windows, sid

I read a list of SIDs from the registry, `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`.

How would one resolve the display username (e.g. `DOMAIN\user`, `BUILT-IN\user`)  given the SID string in C#?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Win32 API function [`LookupAccountSid()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379166%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is used to find the name that corresponds to a SID.

`LookupAccountSid()` has the following signature:

```
BOOL LookupAccountSid(LPCTSTR lpSystemName, PSID Sid,LPTSTR Name, LPDWORD cbName,
                       LPTSTR ReferencedDomainName, LPDWORD cbReferencedDomainName,
                       PSID_NAME_USE peUse);
```

MSDN [Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379166(VS.85).aspx).

Here's the P/Invoke reference (with sample code): http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.LookupAccountSid

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool LookupAccountSid (
  string lpSystemName,
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] Sid,
  StringBuilder lpName,
  ref uint cchName,
  StringBuilder ReferencedDomainName,
  ref uint cchReferencedDomainName,
  out SID_NAME_USE peUse);
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do it without using p/invoke in C#?

Comment: @DennisC you can do it without P/Invoke. Please see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593005/convert-sid-to-username-in-c-sharp/7593200

Comment: @EriawanKusumawardhono I guess you may not read the questions very well.  Because they are exactly opposite API

Answer (score 31):

Just found it on the [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32.LookupAccountSid).

Alternative Managed API:
Available in .Net 2.0:

```
using System.Security.Principal;

// convert the user sid to a domain\name
string account = new SecurityIdentifier(stringSid).Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).ToString();
```

Comment: This solution is not reliable in all situations. There are sometimes SIDs which cannot be translated and this will throw an exception. I've found LookupAccountSid() to be more reliable.