# NetworkService permission (multi-language)

Tags: vb.net, permissions, globalization

So, I'm doing a setup project, all written in VB.NET, and I need to give to the NetworkService account, permission on a certain folder.

The following code works perfect (Windows 7 - en-US):

```
Dim dInfo As New DirectoryInfo("C:\FolderOrFileToGivePermission")
Dim dSecurity As DirectorySecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl()
dSecurity.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule("NETWORK SERVICE", FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow))
dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity)
```

The problem began when I try this very same code on my Windows 7, Vista or XP (**all in PT-BR**) , I found that there is no "NETWORK SERVICE", the correct name is "Serviço de Rede".

I need to get this name to give permission to the right user.

After a lot of investigation on all 3 OSes, I found that the ID for the user is: "S-1-5-20", his path on the registry is: Computer\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-20
and the default folder for it: C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService

But I still didn't find the actual "localizable" name and I need it to be dynamic, because this system will be installed in a lot of different countries (different machines and cultures).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after more and more research, I've changed my search over Google and stackoverflow, and I've found the answer on another question:

[The best way to resolve display username by SID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380031/the-best-way-to-resolve-display-username-by-sid/380206#380206)

```
Dim NetworkServiceName as String = new SecurityIdentifier("S-1-5-20").Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).ToString();
```

Comment: I'm just curious if you used "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService" instead of "NETWORK SERVICE" would it work.

Comment: I've tried on Vista pt-BR before posting the question and didn't worked, aparently because "NT AUTHORITY" is "AUTORIDADE NT" on pt-BR

Answer (score 6):

Use the [System.Security.Principal.WellKnownSidType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.wellknownsidtype.aspx) enumeration:

```
SecurityIdentifier networkService = new SecurityIdentifier(
    WellKnownSidType.NetworkServiceSid, null);

FileSystemAccessRule rule = new FileSystemAccessRule(
    networkService, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
```

Comment: It seems like a cleaner and better solution, unfortunately I do not work on the company anymore, and I can't test it on the project.