# How to get all accounts including Local System account in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

Im developing a winforms wizard and in one page of this wizard i need to list all the accounts to enable the user select one. So my working code is:

```
  private static IEnumerable<string> GetUsersAccountName()
    {
        var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(new SelectQuery("Win32_UserAccount"));
        var usersAccounts = (from ManagementBaseObject envVar in searcher.Get()
                     select envVar["Name"].ToString());

        return users.ToList();
    }
```

So with this method i get the name of the accounts, but not get the "local system account", how to get this account name too?

Comment: LocalSystem is not part of that mechanic; it's ignored by the security system. If you really need it, just add it manually

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240373/how-do-i-get-the-current-username-in-net-using-c
is this what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 1):

You're right, there's a little stuff you need to do, in order to receive the account name. You can do look up by SID. In fact, SID is always the same for LocalSystem([S-1-5-18](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc980032.aspx)).

To actually convert it, try this:

```
string localSysAccountName = new SecurityIdentifier("S-1-5-18")
                     .Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).ToString();
```

In case that does not seem to work well, have a look at [LookupAccountSid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380031/the-best-way-to-resolve-display-username-by-sid).